# C# DataGridView is not updating with DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

i have a DataTable with some data and i bind it with my DataGridView with this code:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Measures.Table;
```

In separate thread i read data from connected device and insert that into my DataTable with this code:

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row[ "Time" ] = dt;
foreach ( var kvp in measures )
    row[ kvp.Key ] = kvp.Value;
table.Rows.Add( row );
```

On my Form I am able to change it's main control with a button. Both controls are UserControl, of which one consists the dataGridView1 DataGridView. When I add a row to my DataTable, my DataGridView does not update, until I switch to the other control, and move back to the one with DGV.

I have read some solutions on stack, which basically tell me that i should use BindingSource, but this code:

```
BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = Measures.Table;
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

does not work as well.

I don't know why this happens, because I have also created a simple app with just DGV and DataTable updated with Timer.Tick event and it works there. Anyone knows any reason why this DGV is not updating itself? It updates itself only when forced to redraw (with switching controls or just form resize)

Comment: It is not clear if you are using a reference to the same object. If the code that add the new row does it against a different instance of the table, then you should expect this behavior

Comment: it is the same instance. `Measures` is a singleton with which i handle both adding data to datatable, logging them to a file and some other stuff. `Measures.Table` is just a dumb property `{ get { return table } }`. Also, as I have wrote above, i only have to force redraw with anything (like resizing form) and DGV will show what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the culprit ... (Me ;P). The reason, that it works in a small simple app and it doesn't in my main app is quite simple:

1. main app actualizes `DataTable` (later called `DT`) in a `BackgroundWorker`, in which I am pooling the device for availability of new data. `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event is running aside from UI thread, so if I am updating `DT` there, it fires all `DT` events in the same thread, so UI actually does not know of any change in `DT`.
2. simple app based on `Timer.Tick` - `Tick` event is fired in UI thread, so `Invoke` is not required, and every event of changed `DataTable` is fired in UI thread, which lets `DGV` to react to any change.

in other words, to make it work, without `DGV.Refresh()` or `DGV.Items.Refresh()` I've had to update `DataTable` in UI thread, here's how I am doing this:

```
var form = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[0];
...
form.BeginInvoke( (Action)( () => CODE_THAT_ADDS_ROW_TO_DATATABLE ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

First, a data grid binds to a DataView of a data table, and handles internally to use the source.DefaultView.

After your records are added to the table, issue a refresh via the Items...

dataGridView1.Items.Refresh();

You should not have to rebind the source... just caution if you are doing the items.refresh from a different thread because the grid is UI based and not behind-the-scenes.

Comment: DGV does not have `Items` property (maybe that's because I work with WinForms), but do have a `Refresh()` method. Calling `Refresh` from different thread is not a problem with `Invoke` in hand ;) This (`Refresh()`)partially solves my problem. DGV updates, but is always 1 record behind (when i have 2 records in table, i will have only 1 in DGV, it stays like that even after my measurements are stopped). I am refreshing DGV in `DataTable.TableNewRow` event. ... Anyway, thanks, for now only upvote, as I am trying to find a bit better solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget this line

```
datatable.AcceptChanges();
```